# How to structure data for flutter Cart flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling with flutter ecommerce cart data structure for firebase , what is the right way to structure the data?

for now I am structuring it someting like this on firebase :

```
cart_items = [
        {
            "id": 144,
            "created_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:04",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:04",
            "cart_id": "3",
            "client_id": "83",
            "product_id": "6",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "1500",
            "name": "Cucumber (2Pcs)",
            "image": "products/es4eGjkgQ6MvzTaMyX4iXWjcSX03mVk3QB9oODWk.jpeg",
           },
        {
            "id": 145,
            "created_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:09",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-04 14:42:09",
            "cart_id": "3",
            "client_id": "83",
            "product_id": "5",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "2000",
            "name": "Cauliflower",
            "image": "products/lVZ31zORzltyVIDXhHoCWUgjTlal7cWd7pI8DL2V.jpeg",
            }
    ]
```

But the problem with this is I am not able to update the quantity field of the product.

Comment: "I am not able to update the quantity field of the product." Why not? What is keeping you from doing so? In general, you'll get much better help on Stack Overflow if you include the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Following the guidances in that link drastically increases the chance that someone can help.

Comment: well I am unable to update the quanitiy field as it is present inside a map whihch is present inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

*quantity* field must be integer or number not string then you can use ***FieldValue.increment(itemCount)*** for updating quantity value also I see
*cart_id*, *client_id*, *product_id*, *price* fields are also string change it to integer or number

Comment: how do I update it ? i did tried FieldValue.increment method by converting the quantity to integer, but the problem i faced is updateing the field of the quantity.

Comment: const userRef = db.collection('documents').doc('document_id');
const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

userRef.update({ FieldToIncrease: increment });